# Retrieve Data in an ArrayList with C#

Tags: c#, collections, arraylist

I'm having problems retrieving data from an ArrayList collection using C#. I'm saving a class into an ArrayList. The code works in saving the data, but I don't know how to write the code to retrieve it. I thought that **_serviceList [0]._displayName** would retrieve the first item, but it fails. How can I view all the items in the ArrayList?

Thanks.

```
class Service
{
  public string _displayName;
  public ServiceControllerStatus _status;

  public Service ()
  {
    _displayName = "";
    _status = ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped;
  }

  public Service (string displayName, ServiceControllerStatus status)
  {
    _displayName = displayName;
    _status = status;
  }
}

class Program
{
  public static ArrayList _serviceList = new ArrayList ();

  public Program ()
  {
    _serviceList = null;
  }

  static void Main (string [] args)
  {
    .
    .
    .

    _serviceList.Add (new Service (service.DisplayName, service.Status));
  }

  // The following code doesn't work.
  Console.WriteLine (_serviceList [0]._displayName);
```

Comment: I would avoid using ArrayList in C#, period. Instead, use a generic list of something you know the type of: `List<Service> services = new List<Service>();`

Comment: You forgot to unbox element form the list

((type of your element)mylist[0]).somePropertyofTheElement="asdf";

Comment: Thanks @VP. Your right that List is a better choice than ArrayList. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working on .Net framework 2.0 or higher then use [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) a generic , type safe version for List, and just changing the `line`

```
public static ArrayList _serviceList = new ArrayList ();
```

To

```
public static List<Service> _serviceList = new List<Service>();
```

would solve your issue.

**But,** if you are working on lower framework than 2.0 then you have to explicitly cast the object to `Service` like:

```
Console.WriteLine (((Service)_serviceList [0])._displayName);
```

since `ArrayList` would return it as of type `object` and not `Service`

Comment: Thanks @Habb. That did it. I can retrieve data using:

    foreach (var s in _serviceList)
      Console.Write (s._displayName);